# Production vs staging environment in Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, production, staging, azure-cloud-services

I have two roles in my project, web and  worker role. Both are connected by a service bus.

When I do the deploy to staging everything works ok, but when I do the swap
and I make changes to the staging worker role I get inconsistencies.

Apparently my requests from front end sometimes makes the worker role of production and sometimes worker role of staging.

Comment: Are you using a separate service bus for staging?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with worker-roles, the concept of Production and Staging environment does not make as much sense and does not apply as much as when it does for Websites.

I highly suggest that during deployment, if you have incompatible changes between new release and existing release, in the way that they process data, that you shutdown production deployment, then bring the new deployment in the staging slot... validate that it works, swap, and delete old-produciton, now new-staging deployment.  But avoid having both old and new deployments run at the same time, when they conflict in how they process data.

HTH